# How to get 1st image from page within certain class using jquery and put in meta tag?

Tags: jquery, image, class

How can I get the 1st (or only) image from a page that lies within a certain class using jquery? ...then put that link into a face book image meta tag?

eg: `<meta property="og:image" content="some image link" />`

http://jsfiddle.net/M49hC/1/

```
 // when click on #btn3
  $('#btn3').click(function(){
   var yo = $('img').children('.clsa');
   alert(yo.getAttribute('src'))
  });

<a href="http://coursesweb.net/javascript/" title="JavaScript Course" class="clsa"><img src="http://www.example.com/ya1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="http://coursesweb.net/javascript/" title="JavaScript Course" class="clsa"><img src="http://www.example.com/ya2.jpg" /></a>
<button id="btn3">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M49hC/2/)</kbd>

```
$('#btn3').click(function () {
     var yo = $('.clsa:first').children('img:first');
     alert(yo.prop('src'))
});
```

---

Updated After OP's comment

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M49hC/3/)</kbd>

```
$('#btn3').click(function () {
    var yo = $('.clsa:first').children('img:first');
    $('body').prepend('<meta property="og:image" content="' + yo.prop('src') + '" />')
   //Instead of $('body').prepend() you can also use $('head').append() if you want to put meta tag in head
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the first `.clsa` element and then find the image inside it. To get the src attribute you need to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
 // when click on #btn3
 $('#btn3').click(function () {
     var yo = $('.clsa:first').children('img');
     alert(yo.attr('src'))
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2j7bE/)

If there are chances that there will be `.clsa` elements without `img` as a child then try

```
// when click on #btn3
$('#btn3').click(function () {
    var yo = $('.clsa:has(img):first').find('img');
    alert(yo.attr('src'))
});
```

This will find the fist `clsa` element which has a image as a descendant element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tv98s/)

Answer (score 1):

The code should look something like this:

```
var img = $(".clsa").children("img")[0];
var meta = $("<meta>", {property: "og-image", content: img.src});
$("head").append(meta);
```

Comment: Getting the image src works but for some reason it will not append to head

Comment: @JizboJonez strange: I recall having some problems when doing stuff in the head, but I thought it mighta been only in IE 8. I'm on mobile, so you'll have to experiment. Does ``prepend`` work as in ``$("head").prepend(meta)``? You can always use something like ``$("title").after(meta)``, which I'm pretty sure will work, although I would recommend ``$("body").prepend(meta)`` because that dosen't require a title tag. You'd want to place it as near to the top of the file as possible (and not use ``$("body").append(meta)``), because a script looking for this tag might only download x bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've abandoned trying to do things this way as I hear it is not a good idea due to the fact that the meta is added after page load which is too late for facebook to pick it up. So I accomplished what I needed using pure php instead. Cheers

Comment: @JizboJonez great! I didn't even think that you'd need a non-JavaScript method. It would make sense, though, since some webpage readers don't run scripts.